# Angular 4 - Error encountered resolving symbol values statically in routes

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

Please help. Am trying to lazy load a module depending on the device type, but getting an error: "ERROR in Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Only initialized variables and constants can be referenced because the value of this variable is needed by the template compiler..."

Here is the code:

//routing.ts

```
export declare var MobileDetect: any;
export var devicePath;

export var deviceType = new MobileDetect(window.navigator.userAgent);
  if (deviceType.phone() != null) {
    devicePath = 'app/mobile/mobile.module#MobileModule';
  }
  else{
    devicePath = 'app/desktop/desktop.module#DesktopModule';
  }

import { ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', loadChildren: devicePath}
];

export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(routes);
```

Comment: are you doing AOT ?

Comment: Yes sorry forgot to mention I'm building in AOT.

Answer (score 0):

When using AOT route should be statically analyzable. What you can try to do is to provide ROUTES using a factory.
Change :

```
RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
```

To

```
RouterModule.forRoot([]);
```

And define these two providers:

```
providers: [
{provide: ANALYZE_FOR_ENTRY_COMPONENTS, multi: true, useValue: routes},
{provide: ROUTES, multi: true, useFactory: getRoutes}]
```

(ANALYZE_FOR_ENTRY_COMPONENTS is from @angular/core and ROUTES from @angular/router)

and the following factory:

```
export function getRoutes(): Routes {
  return routes;
}
```

This example has been taken from:
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/5754